# Using an enterprise app for Single App Mode with Profile Manager in Mavericks Server (MDM)

Tags: macos, ipad, mdm

I have a bunch of iPads that are all supervised, and that are enrolled into a MDM server (Mavericks Server). I've added the app to the specific device group, but when I go to the profile settings and Single App Mode the only apps I can select are the builtin ones.

Is there no way to use a third party (enterprise) app as the app for Single App Mode?

EDIT: If you use Apple Configurator and add the app there you can set Single App Mode to use that app, I would imagine that would be possible when doing the same in Apple's Profile Manager, but it doesn't seem to be working here.

EDIT2: Looking at Apple's documentation it does indeed seem to be possible to select a third party app for single app mode using their Profile Manager, so why isn't the app showing in the list for me?

http://images.apple.com/education/docs/assessment_with_ipad_mar2013_v2.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the Device Group, after installing the app (that you want to show in Single App Mode dropdown and lock it to) do "Update Info" (small icon in bottom-middle-left of screen) on all the devices in that group. Wait a bit, then go to Single App Mode screen again, the app should start appearing.Works for me. The "Update Info" thing also works for Single Device as well and you can lock to any new app installed from Profile Manger, doesn't matter if the app was installed while supervising through Configurator or not.

Comment: For some reason after doing this and going to the single app mode dropdown the dropdown only says "Loading apps…" before I click it. Doesn't matter how long I let it stay before clicking, it's only populated by the builtin apps.

All devices in the group have the same app installed (from the group settings), but not all of them are online anymore. Is this why it won't update?

Comment: First try this thing with individual device rather than with a group. 

For it to work in a group, all devices in the group should :-
— have that app. 
— And all devices with "Update Info". 

One thing i noticed is even in an existing group (with the "new app" already showing in single app mode dropdown), if you add a device to the group (which didn't have the "new app" before it was added to group) can make the "new app" disappear from single app mode dropdown.
 So it is possible thats not showing because some of them are offline.

Answer (score 0):

So interestingly enough in the new update for Server (3.1.1) this seems to be working. The Enterprise app is now listed in the dropdown box.

However there also is about 10 empty items in the box with no text description. So it's clearly still a bit buggy.